# pl/sql--COLLECTIONS AND RECORD

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables called "AA" and "AB"

- In table "AA" I have columns like cust_no, name, address, etc..
- In table "AB" I have one column `cuno`

I need to fetch cust_no from "AA" table and put it into cuno column of "AB" table.

I tried some code here...

```
declare
  Type Ty_Handoff_Pc Is Table Of aa%Rowtype Index By Binary_Integer;
  Type sam Is Table Of ab%rowtype;
  l_pc Ty_Handoff_Pc;
  l_ab sam;
begin
  select distinct cust_no bulk collect into l_pc from aa;
  for j in 1 .. 10 loop 
    l_ab(j) := l_pc(j).cust_no;
    insert into ab values l_ab(j);
  end loop;
end;
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 3):

jonearles, is right, the best way is to use regular SQL - insert + select.

If you have some business logic that requires row-by-row processing in PL/SQL, however, you can use a slightly different variant of what you had:

```
declare
  Type Ty_Handoff_Pc Is Table Of aa%Rowtype Index By Binary_Integer;
  Type sam Is Table Of ab%rowtype;
  l_pc Ty_Handoff_Pc;
  l_ab sam;
begin

  select distinct cust_no bulk collect into l_pc from aa;

  for j in 1 .. l_pc.count loop 
    l_ab(j).cuno := l_pc(j).cust_no;
    -- perhaps some other processing here...
  end loop;

  FORALL i in 1..l_ab.count
    insert into ab values l_ab(i);

end;
```

The advantage of the FORALL at the end is that the insert is done using a bulk in-bind array, so only one call to the SQL engine instead of one for each record.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You cannot bulk collect into an associative array.  You should use a nested table defined based on the column type instead of the table rowtype.</strike>

```
declare
    type Ty_Handoff_Pc is table of aa.cust_no%type;
    Type sam Is Table Of ab%rowtype;
    l_pc Ty_Handoff_Pc;
begin
    select distinct cust_no bulk collect into l_pc from aa;

    for j in 1 .. l_pc.count loop
        insert into ab values(l_pc(j));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Edit: As Jeffrey Kemp pointed out, you can bulk collect into an associative array.

If this is real code, and not just for learning, you should definitely do it in regular SQL.  `insert into ab(custno) select distinct cust_no from aa` will be much faster than using PL/SQL.

Comment: BTW: You *can* bulk collect into an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
type taba is recor(cust_no aa.cust_no%type);
type tabb is table of taba;
custno_t tabb;
begin 
select cust_no bulk collect into custno_t from aa;
forall i in custno_t.first..custno_t.last
insert into bb values custno_t(i);
commit;
end;
```